# C# : concatenate 2 MP3 files

Tags: c#, merge, mp3, concatenation

I tried to concatenate 2 MP3 files using the code below. I got a new file which I can play the first half of (complete first file), but the second half is silent. The length of the new file was correct. What do I do wrong?

```
List<Byte[]> files = new List<byte[]>();
var tempfile = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "1.mp3"));
files.Add(tempfile);
tempfile = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "2.mp3"));
files.Add(tempfile);
Byte[] a=new Byte[files[0].Length+files[1].Length];
Array.Copy(files[0], a, files[0].Length);
Array.Copy(files[1], a, files[1].Length);

File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "3.mp3") , a);
```

Comment: do both files have the same bitrate?

Comment: yes and :
do i have to cut the header of the second file or something like that

Comment: there is a bug in your code.  you are only hearing the second song.  see my answer below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am willing to bet you are only hearing the second song.  (and that either both files are the same length or the first is shorter)

You are copying the second song data over the first.  And MP3 data is streaming so you can just append the files to each other without worrying about bitrates (while they may glitch) the bitrate should automaticly adjust.

Detail on [MP3 Frame headers](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)

... try this...

```
Array.Copy(files[0], 0, a, 0, files[0].Length);
Array.Copy(files[1], 0, a, files[0].Length, files[1].Length);
```

... or better still...

```
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(path, "3.mp3")))
{
    var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "1.mp3"));
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "2.mp3"));
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Flush();
}
```

Comment: this will sort of work, but you'll likely get ID3 tags sitting in the middle of the output file. It's best to strip those out (at least for subsequent files)

Comment: Very true, but because of the frame headers this should not affect the audio.

Comment: Steaming? Or did you mean Streaming?

Comment: I've come across a lot of answers, and this worked. Have yet to find an explanation of stripping the headers, but it didn't seem to affect the audio when I tested it.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
public static void Combine(string[] mp3Files, string mp3OuputFile)
{
    using (var w = new  BinaryWriter(File.Create(mp3OuputFile)))
    {
        new List<string>(mp3Files).ForEach(f => w.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(f)));
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you create a list just to iterate over the set?  just use the foreach keyword.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can concatenate MP3 files using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com):

```
public static void Combine(string[] inputFiles, Stream output)
{
    foreach (string file in inputFiles)
    {
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);
        if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
        {
            output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData,
                         0,
                         reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
        }
        Mp3Frame frame;
        while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {
            output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/11/merging-mp3-files-with-naudio-in-c-and.html) for more information.

Comment: where is the rest mark ? how do you save stream output as a new mp3 file ? tell me please ty how do you call this Combine function where is the before ?

Comment: This solution does not work under Linux - you will get: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'Msacm32.dll' or one of its dependencies. More info: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/472

Answer (score 2):

Each MP3 file has a header at the beginning of the file containing the metadata of the song. At the very least you will have to remove that on the second file.

Here is a previous Stack Overflow question, [How do I merge/join MP3 files with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c).

Here's another link to [Read MP3 Tag Information (ID3v1 and ID3v2)](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4684/read-mp3-tag-information-id3v1-and-id3v2/), it might help you remove it.

Comment: maybe just skipping those many bytes will help. You can find more information about MP3 file format here http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160888/how-do-i-merge-join-mp3-files-with-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875421/how-do-i-seamlessly-concatenate-mp3-streams). Also see [reading MP3 Headers in C#](http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=79&printer=t), but instead of reading the header you just want to strip it off, concatenate the rest, then generate a new header for the concatenated file.

**Edit**: After further reading apparently it doesn't make any difference if you just concatenate the files without stripping the ID3 tags. But it still seems like a good idea to strip them out first.

Comment: i cant find anything in this posts which helps me. How can i cut off the header?

Comment: find out where it ends, and start copying there

Answer (score 2):

As all knows, the Mp3 files are just some *frames* and you can concatenate the streams together:

```
public static void Concatenate(params string[] mp3filenames)
{
    Stream w = File.OpenWrite("D:\\out.mp3");

    foreach (string filename in mp3filenames)
        File.OpenRead(filename).CopyTo(w);    

    w.Flush();
    w.Close();
}
```

and hears the usage:

```
Concatenate("D:\\1.mp3", "D:\\2.mp3");
```